# Read web.config from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am unable to read by web.config. My web.config is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="datalayers" type="Basic" />
 </configSections>

 <maplayers>

  <openlayers projection="EPSG:900913" displayProjection="EPSG:27700"/>
 </maplayers>
</configuration>
```

To read I am doing the following

```
var conn = '<%=ConfigurationManager.maplayers.displayprojection %>'
alert(conn);
```

My page does not load as there is something obviously wrong. PLEASE help.

Reading property in ASP.NET

```
 [ConfigurationProperty( "displayprojection", IsRequired = false )]
 public string DisplayProjection
 {
   get { return (string)this[ "displayprojection" ]; }
   set { this[ "displayprojection" ] = value; }
 }
```

Trying to write to json in ASP.NET

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
if ( DisplayProjection != string.Empty )
{
  writer.WritePropertyName( "displayProjection" );
  writer.WriteValue( DisplayProjection );
}

  writer.WriteEnd();
```

Comment: Define "does not load". Do you get an error? Do you get an HTTP status code?

Comment: What does the console write for the error? have yu tried to put a '.ToString()' after?

Comment: I tried to put ToString() but my page does not load. There is no http error but the page just hangs. What is the right way to get web.cofig values via ASP.NET to javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET can only generate dynamic content for ASCX, ASPX or similarly server generated pages.  If you're trying to add those tags to the JavaScript it's not going to work.

If this is a JavaScript file it will fail because the server passes JavaScript files as plain text files to the browser.

`var conn = '<%=ConfigurationManager.maplayers.displayprojection %>'`
`alert(conn);`

It's not clear from your question, but my guess is your alert dialog contains the actual literal string "<%=ConfigurationManager.maplayers.displayprojection %>" and that is the problem you are having.

Instead add it to the ASPX page in the header like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var conn = '<%=ConfigurationManager.maplayers.displayprojection %>'
    alert(conn);
</script>
...
```

Comment: I understand its not going to work via the javascript (as explained by you)

My ASP.NET code reads it and displays in json. Unfortunately that is not working either. I have added my ASP code in the main question

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config is not available on the client side. It is protected by the web server and not served out. Web.config files often contain sensitive information such as connection strings (passwords). Do you have a good reason for making that available on the client side?

Comment: He's not reading it from the client side. He's reading it from the server side (incorrectly).

Comment: True, but the warning against doing that still stands.

Comment: If he wants to read a custom property in his web.config from the server-side and display that string to the end user, it's not necessarily a security issue.

Comment: I guess, what he is trying to do is reading a specific value from web.config not all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/77917/Read-Configuration-Settings-of-Web-config-using-Ja

i think it can help you